# Animation on the View

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a view like this

[image]

When a user clicks on any button like say "Audi".

what I want is to show a view above of this with animation like
[image]

What I have tried is

I make a layout like this (Just for test the animation)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/hideLayout"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:background="#f0f"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_showView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show View" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and then make animation like

`Animation showView=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_showView);`

and my anim file is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

</set>
```

and then

```
showView=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_showView);

    showView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            hideLayout.startAnimation(animShow);
            animShow.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    hideLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    hideLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            });

        }
    });
```

It is working but not how I want. the `text View` is coming from the bottom. I hope my image shows what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this android:fromYDelta="-100%p" instead of android:fromYDelta="100%p"

Comment: NO it will start from the -ve bottom of the screen.

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem Have u got any solution?

Comment: @parag what I found, I wrote in my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for android >=3.0, `Object Animator`

I fix the height of the view as it is not a problem in my case.

I make two view

1) Top View width fix height 100dip(Which need to be animate) make it invisible

2) Bottom View fix height 100dip(Visible)

3) when I click `showView` I call following lines

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(topLayout,
            "y", 100, 0);
objectAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            topLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            showView.bringToFront();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
            objectAnimator.setDuration(500);
    objectAnimator.start();
```

may be it will help some one. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `TextView` is coming from bottom because of the `android:fromYDelta="100%p"` in your code. If you want your textView to move up from its original position then use following code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

       <translate
            android:duration="500"
            android:toYDelta="-66%"
            android:fromYDelta="0%" />

   </set>
```

Change the value `-66%`  as per your requirement

From the image what i can guess is that you want the parent layout of  `Marke: Audi` to slide in and out.
For that you will have to animate the parent layout(parent of the layout you want to slide in and out) and also have to fix the height ratio of the two views. And then on Animation end just change the visibility of upper view to  `GONE`.

Comment: It will come from top to bottom. what I want is from bottom to top.

Comment: sorry my mistake just reverse the values of <code>from</code> and <code>to</code>. Editing my code.

Answer (score 0):

try to make res -> anim folder

slide_in_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="-100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

slide_in_top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

slide_out_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
   android:fromYDelta="0"
   android:toYDelta="100%p" />
```

slide_out_top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="-100%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_top);

Comment: I know this. But it will be valid for the `fill_parent` case.